# NSView with NSBezierPath not updating after window resize

Tags: swift, nsview, window-resize

I probably miss something obvious, but...

I have a simple NSView:

```
class TestView : NSView {

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let path = NSBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(NSPoint(x: 0 ,y: 0))
    path.lineToPoint(NSPoint(x: frame.size.width, y: 0))
    path.lineToPoint(NSPoint(x: frame.size.width, y: frame.size.height))
    path.lineToPoint(NSPoint(x: 0 ,y: frame.size.height))
    path.lineToPoint(NSPoint(x: 0 ,y: 0))
    path.lineWidth = 1
    path.stroke()
  }
}
```

This is placed sole in a window. The window controller has

```
func windowDidEndLiveResize(notification: NSNotification) {
  var frame = textFrame
  frame.size.height = window!.frame.size.height - 60
  frame.size.width = window!.frame.size.width - 40
  field.frame = frame
  field.needsDisplay = true
}
```

where `frame` is the size of the frame on window load and `field` is my `TestView`. So when I start my app it will draw the frame nicely as expected:

[image]

But when scaled down

[image]

it appears that the view is not erased and it leaves artifacts on the window.
It's probably something trivial, but I'm currently blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the superview to redraw and clear that visual artifact using `field.superview?.needsDisplay = true`.

Depending on your goals, you might want to use `windowDidResize(notification: NSNotification)` instead which will continually update the view while the window is being resized.

Comment: Wow. I knew it was something simple. I was sure that the superview already knew about needsDisplay. Obviously it did not. Thanks :-)